# MergEXT MergZXing layer and barcode not reading

Tags: livecode

Just started working with this awesome external but have a couple of questions.

When the control is evoked, is it always the top layer or can I have a background transparent image on top of it so I can frame the control nicely?

Also, my testing seems to read most Barcodes but when it comes down to reading Barcodes on hard drives, the control does not want to decode those.... Too dense of bar code pattern?

I am very impressed thus far with the ease of use of your externals.  Makes we want to code more for mobile devices!

Comment: What barcode on harddrives do you mean. The very small one which looks like a qr code?

Answer (score 1):

an overlaying transparent image is not possible, as far as i know.

but couldn´t you use

```
command mergZXingControlSetRect pLeft,pTop,pRight,pBottom
```

to define  the rect of that scanner after creation

or

```
command mergZXingControlCreate pLeft,pTop,pRight,pBottom
```

to create the scanner control in the specified rect.

Set the rect smaller than the width and the height of the screen.

You could then use an underlying image, which is displayed outside of the scanner rect, to show the frame around scanner control. Did not test it myself, but i would assume that this should work.

Comment: Yes, that works but only in a "boxy" sense.  I was trying to do something g a little more stylized.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the native controls in externals and the ones the engine provides are added as views on top of the LiveCode view. That means you can't intermingle LiveCode controls with them. One thing that some users have done is add a web view with a transparent background and a load a png image. If you create the barcode view first and the web view second then the web view will be on top.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this approach and see what kind of results I get.